# ggplot2 - alternative to geom_ribbon for non continuous x values with facet

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to plot a ribbon around a `hline` in a graph with barplots divided in facets. The x axis is non continuous and even though I have tried different solutions like making x numeric for geom_ribbon, I can't find a solution.

```
toplot=structure(list(size = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L), density = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("control", 
"low", "medium", "high", "extreme"), class = "factor"), mean = c(0.649495617453177, 
0.595030456501759, 0.671853292620394, 0.772710452129729, 0.208287258947775, 
0.113070097194118, 0.138593272196695, 0.106836463449531, 0.142217123599047, 
0.291860533054406, 0.187033701620647, 0.12045308442074, 0, 0.0000389132497170763, 
0.00251973356226341, 0), sd = c(0.0472308191904496, 0.0716594048000388, 
0.0857233139528986, 0.0534307204561747, 0.0481240616513752, 0.0390094013972726, 
0.0412224562146842, 0.0278742510208481, 0.0233346723409426, 0.0559831409664118, 
0.0494588911471589, 0.0270924698136921, 0, 0.000218839700404029, 
0.00550243848896909, 0), period = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), class = "factor", .Label = "final")), .Names = c("size", 
"density", "mean", "sd", "period"), row.names = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L), class = "data.frame") 

contr=structure(list(size = c(10L, 30L, 50L, 100L), density = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("control", "low", "medium", "high", "extreme"
), class = "factor"), mean = c(0.640615964924125, 0.231731093831607, 
0.122309113981835, 0.0053438272624331), sd = c(0.04503167947312, 
0.0406874041671366, 0.0173288744394121, 0.00181433175554796), 
    period = c("final", "final", "final", "final")), .Names = c("size", 
"density", "mean", "sd", "period"), row.names = c(1L, 6L, 11L, 
16L), class = "data.frame")
```

and the code that I have

```
p <- ggplot(data=toplot,aes(x=period,y=mean,fill=density)) +
       geom_bar(stat='identity',position = 'dodge') +
       facet_grid(~size) +
       geom_hline(data = contr, aes(yintercept = mean,linetype = "control"),size=1.2) +
       scale_linetype_manual(name = "",values=2)
```

I would like to draw a ribbon around the horizontal control line but it's not working. This doesn't draw anything and changes the fill.

```
p + geom_ribbon(data=contr, aes(ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd),fill='grey')
```

and this also messes up the facets

```
p + geom_ribbon(data=contr, aes(x=1:4, ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd),fill='grey')
```

I have also tried to use group=size to match the facet command but nothing happens.

Either I am using the wrong geom or I am missing how to structure the data. I tried to use this http://mjskay.github.io/tidybayes/reference/geom_lineribbon.html but it doesn't exist in ggplot2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects like `geom_ribbon` expect a series of x and y values, so that points can be connected via lines. The main problem here is that your x-axis has only 1 value ('final'), so there's nothing to connect. You can get around the problem with `geom_rect`, which only needs values for the upper-right and lower-left corners. We simply use `-Inf` and `Inf` for the xmin and xmax values, so that the rectangle spans the full width of each facet:

```
p <- ggplot(data=toplot,aes(x=period,y=mean,fill=density)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity',position = 'dodge') +
  facet_grid(~size) +
  geom_rect(data = contr, aes(ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd), xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, alpha = 0.25, fill = 'black') +
  geom_hline(data = contr, aes(yintercept = mean,linetype = "control"),size=1.2) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "",values=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant and simple, I didn't think about the geom_rect. thanks! Just a question, why in my legend control doesn't have the shaded area like your does?

Comment: Hard to say! My code produces the plot shown. I can’t speculate on new code you may or may not be running. :)

Comment: Cleary, but I was rather asking if there is any command associated to that behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The `geom_rect()` approach is nice. You could do something similar with `geom_crossbar()`:

```r
p <- ggplot(data=toplot,aes(x=period,y=mean,fill=density)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity',position = 'dodge') +
  facet_grid(~size) +
  geom_crossbar(data = contr, 
                aes(ymin = (mean - 2*sd), 
                    ymax=(mean + 2*sd), linetype = "control"), 
                size=.2, alpha=.5, width=1, fill='darkgrey') +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "",values=2)
p + theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: nice solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. Modify the size=7 value to change the thickness of the line; and alpha=0.2 to edit transparency.

```
p <- ggplot(data=toplot,aes(x=period,y=mean,fill=density)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity',position = 'dodge') +
  facet_grid(~size) +
  geom_hline(data = contr, aes(yintercept = mean),size=7,alpha=0.2) +
  geom_hline(data = contr, aes(yintercept = mean,linetype = "control"),size=1.2) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "",values=2)
```

[image: the plot]

Comment: No this doesn't work because the size of the shaded region is determined by actual values and it's not the same for every facet. Nice try though.